# Why do I get this error with Eigen in C++?

Tags: c++, eigen

I am trying to use Eigen in C++ with tensors, and I get error for both
the `new` command below and the addition command.

How do I create a new tensor with specific dimensions in each "mode" (a 3 x 3 matrix in this case), and how do I add two tensors of such type?

Also, what would I need to do to take *tensor and multiply it with itself (through tensor contraction) on one of the modes to get a new 3 x 3 tensor?

```
#include <eigen/Eigen/Core>
#include <eigen/unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/Tensor>


int main()
{
    Tensor<double, 2>* tensor;

    tensor = new Tensor<double, 2>(3,3);

    (*tensor) = (*tensor) + (*tensor);
}
```

The errors I get: for the new statement:

```
Field `Tensor' must be static.
```

For the addition statement:

```
Class `complex<Tensor<double,2,0,DenseIndex>>' is not compatiable with class 'Tensor<double,2,0,DenseIndex>'.
```

Answer (score 0):

gcc-5.4, libeigen3-dev on ubu16, the following compiles for me:

// g++ --std=c++11 -I/usr/include/eigen3 test2.cpp -Wall -o test2

```
#include <Eigen/Core>
#include <unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/Tensor>


int main()
{
    Eigen::Tensor<double, 2>* tensor;

    tensor = new Eigen::Tensor<double, 2>(3,3);

    (*tensor) = (*tensor) + (*tensor);
}
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/14239115)

Comment: I believe him to be missing the Eigen:: namespace, the include paths look a bit fishy. I've given him or her code to test that this solves his problem and a compilation command line. If Mr/Ms kloop continues to get the same errors with the code above we can narrow down where the problem might be. Or it may well fix the problem. Hopefully time and Mr/Ms kloop will tell!

Comment: So I think you can probably be suspicious of your libeigen installation.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, including an explanation [really helps](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.